# "express congratulation to someone for" VS "express congratulation to someone on"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. He expressed congratulation to you **for** your election as president of America.
> 2. He expressed congratulation to you **on** your election as president of America.

Which preposition is good?

Comment: Related: [Congratulate on or for](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/214251/43052), and [“Congratulate for” vs. “congratulate on”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/70012/202470)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think either word could be used, but the common phrasing of a native speaker would be "congratulations **on** your election." Note that "congratulations" is almost always plural.