# Congratulate on or for

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

A lot of reference is available for this question but I couldn't understand the difference.

That when to use *congratulate on* and when to use *congratulate for*.

Answer (score 3):

Both "on" and "for" are correct. You can use  the prepositions when talking about what someone is praised for. But there seems to be a slight difference. You congratulate someone **on** something when that something is *their* solid achievement. You congratulate someone **for** something when they have *contributed* to something successful:

> I really must congratulate the organisers **for** a well-run and enjoyable event. The employees should be congratulated **for** the part they have played in the success. (it's like we need to *thank* them *for* it)
>
> She congratulated me warmly **on** my performance. (that was just *my* performance) I congratulated him **on** his recent promotion. (that was only *him* who made it happen - his hard work must be the key)

By the way, there is a formal phrase "someone is to be congratulated *for* something." It is a formal way of saying that someone has done well ([Macmillan English Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/someone-is-to-be-congratulated-for-something)):

> Your secretary is to be congratulated **for** his prompt actions. (again, we can rephrase the sentence like this: your secretary is to be *thanked* *for* her prompt actions)

Answer (score 1):

Following these guidelines will allow your sentences to sound more accurate and natural, and less awkward:

**Congratulations on** generally could be followed by a noun. 
- *Congratulations on the new promotion!*
- *Congratulations on your achievements!*
- *Congratulations on the new house!*

**Congratulations for** generally could be followed by a verb.
- *Congratulations for being amazing!*
- *Congratulations for achieving great success!*
- *Congratulations for graduating from college!*

Though of course exceptions arise:
- *Congratulations on making it this far!*
- *Congratulations on losing so much weight!*

But never:
- *Congratulations for the new house!* 
- *Congratulations for the promotion!*

The last two just don’t sound right or natural to me. Others may disagree. Also, when in doubt, you can’t really go wrong with using **congratulations on** in nearly all contexts. I hope this helps! :)

Comment: "Congratulations for" could also be followed by a noun phrase starting with a possessive: "Your secretary is to be congratulated for his prompt actions" (from another answer)

Comment: Yes, exactly! I think the other person answered more thoroughly than I did.

Comment: More thoroughly, but i think less correctly. I don't think that the own achievement vs contributed to is the relevant distinction, but rather the form of the phrase that follows. Which is why I upvoted your answer. But I'm not quite sure.